# Two Issues when installing Bolts via cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, bolts-framework

I've installed Bolts via cocoapods in Xcode 7, now I get 2 errors when I try to build the app.

The first error is

```
'CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use [NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:] instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent (since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid).
```

And the second error is

```
'sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] (see NSURLSession.h
```

The errors are in two different Files, the first is in *BFAppLinkNavigation.m*, the second in *BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.m*.

[Here](https://github.com/telip007/testPods) is the repro.

Comment: have you tried to run with the bolts like this? deprecated doesn't necessarily mean 'completely broken to where you can't run or build'

Comment: @Larcerax could I get problems when I submit it to the App Store with these issues ?

Comment: personally, i would never use something that even gives a small error if I'm building/running for release and even for development. There's devs that will move forward without worrying about these issues but there's a reason things are marked as "deprecated" and you have to consider this fact and decide whether you are going to take the risk. I won't download Xcode 7 until Apple officially releases it so that I don't have to deal with issues like you are seeing.

Comment: Unless you are part of a large dev team or have the time to dedicate to resolving issues like this internally, I would roll back to the previous versions and only update when Apple updates, unless of course you work for a multimillion dollar company backing a top selling app and can't afford NOT to update your users the same day that ios 9 is released.

Comment: and by Update, I mean bolts too, even though bolts is create by Facebook and use for their stuff and Parse's stuff

Comment: @Larcerax thank you, I think I will downgrade now to iOS 8 :D

Comment: lol, you don't have to follow my advice exactly, you will be fine working with IOS 9 and xcode 7, but just know that you are treading on thin ice since you won't find much help here on SO or elsewhere, good luck with whatever you end up doing!